# error: '' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, reference

I was trying to do a simple program to learn a bit more about reference passage, pointers and how to use this 2 on structs in C++ and I got a few questions.

I got an error on the code below "error: 'totalStudent' was not declared in this scope" and my question is, how should I declare the "totalStudent".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct test{
    char name[30];
    int age;
};

void addStudent(struct test *ptrTest,int *totalStudent){
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        cout<<"\nInsert the name: ";
        cin.sync();
        cin.getline(ptrTest->name,sizeof(ptrTest->name));
        cout<<"\nInsert the age: ";
        cin.sync();
        cin>>ptrTest->age;
        *totalStudent+=1;
    }

}

void showStudent(struct test *ptrTest,int totalStudent){
    for(int i=0;i<totalStudent;i++){
    cout<<"\nName: "<<ptrTest->name;
    cout<<"\nAge: "<<ptrTest->age;
    }
};

int main()
{
    struct test t;
    addStudent(&t,&totalStudent);
    showStudent(&t,totalStudent);
    return 0;
}
```

I can't use pointers and reference passages with structures very well. I can only use them when I'm not using structs.

Comment: Note that in C++ you don't need to add `struct` in the declaration of function. I.e. you could have written `void addStudent(test *ptrTest,int *totalStudent)`.

Comment: thank you, I'm still testing so I didn't know how I could do things, thank you :D

Comment: You don't have any references in your program. You are passing by pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to declare this variable in the scope of `main`:

```
int main()
{
    struct test t;
    // LIKE THIS
    int totalStudent;

    addStudent(&t,&totalStudent);
    showStudent(&t,totalStudent);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
Another question, I added to my functions "(ptrTest+i)" instead of just ptrTest so I could store more students but when I give the condition i<totalStudents it is giving me an infinite loop when it is showing, names don't appear and age are only right on the first 2 times it shows.
When I change to i<2 it gives me the right amount but no names still.

Any clue on what it could be? :/

Comment: `ptrTest+i` assumes `ptrTest` points at an array.  `struct test t;` is not an array.